# How to convert string to array in PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, converters

I have string:

```
$my_string = 'kqxs.mt={run:1,tinh:"39,31",ntime:153801582,delay:2000,kq:{39:{lv:"K42",8:"69",7:"985",6:["7772","4105","0258"],5:"8965",4:["03787","86098","45665"]}}};';
```

Please help me convert this string to array in PHP.

I want result:

```
array(){
   [8]{
         [0]=>69
     },
   [7]{
         [0]=>985
    },
    [6]{
        [0]=>7772
        [1]=>4105
        [2]=>0258
    }
    .............
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What array result you expected from there? Did you tried anything? If yes, what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

You can just treat the string like it's an array:

```
<?php
$my_string = 'kqxs.mt={run:1,tinh:"39,31",ntime:153801582,delay:2000,kq:{39:{lv:"K42",8:"69",7:"985",6:["7772","4105","0258"],5:"8965",4:
"03787","86098","45665"]}}};';
//
for ($x = 0; $x < strlen($my_string); $x++){
echo "<br>".$my_string[$x];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a separator to make a string to became array.
For example: $string = "Hello, beautiful, world";
to make the $string array you need to use explode.
For example: $string_array = explode(",", $string);
The first parameter in explode will be your separator and your second parameter is the string you want to become array.